# Converting java datetime to iso in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I have set up a flow that reads data from a mysql database but having problems with the time-format. Debugging payload gives me "2019-04-22T10:25:07.000Z" and running the query in mysql gives me "2019-04-22 12:26:43". I wasn't running them at the same time but not 2h apart.

Using the date/time formatter Im trying to change it to format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" on msg.payload[0].date, but all it does is showing "2019-04-22 12:04:00".

I should also say that I use a timestamp-injector o update the data from the database every 30sec. Value and datetime updates in msg.payload but not the date after the formatter.

[image: picture on the date/time formatter]

What is it Im doing wrong here?

Sadly I'm new to both Node-RED and Java but hope you can help me.

Comment: ok, after I entered same timezone in the SQL-connector I managed to get it synced but the date/time-formatter still dont work :(

Comment: "2019-04-22 12:04:00". is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" What format are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm receiving the timestamp as "2019-04-22T10:25:07.000Z" and want to show it as "2019-04-22 12:04:00". I guess the two hours it differs is due to another timezone or the format?